# Forcing O(n^2) operations with n actions (Reallocation)

Tags: performance, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have to house an unknown number of people (irrelevant here).

I have an infinite number of rooms, each of which can house a two potency of people (from 2, 4, 8, ...). Moreover, I can only afford one room at a time.

Every time, the room gets too small everyone in **room A** has to move to move to the bigger **room B**. Same procedure occurs when the room is only half filled. In this case everyone has to move from **room B** back to **room A**.

Now there is one person, who hacks my strategy and enters wrong "enter-/leave-" actions, so that the number of people actually housed is wrong (more or less).
I have show that it is possible to force O(n^2) people changing the room with **n "enter/leave"-actions** (n is the number of enter and leave - actions).

Note here that a person who has to change the room x times counts as x times changing the room.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first do n/2 pushBack operations

then the room contains n/2 people

then do n/4 (pushBack + popBack)

for each pushBack, a room with the size of n is allocated and n/2 people are "copied"

for the popBack, a smaller room with the size of n/2 is allocated and each of the n/2 people left are copied inside it.

for a (pushBock + popBock)-operation there are n operations done (coping)

the total effort for all operations (except moving) is in O(n)

this means that for n operations, there are at least (n/4)*n = Θ(n^2) copy-operations